# proc/fd permission errors in some (not all) lxc containers after upgrading host to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, 22.04, lxc

Yesterday I updated an Ubuntu 20.04 machine to 22.04.

lxc is from snap and I believe is unchanged.

It has unprivileged lxc containers running various systems including Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04; Archlinux current; and debian trixie/sid.

In the debian container, since the upgrade, running `fuser` as non-root results in a slew of permission errors. For example:

```
$ fuser .
Cannot stat file /proc/941/fd/0: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/941/fd/1: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/941/fd/2: Permission denied
[...]
Cannot stat file /proc/941/fd/30: Permission denied
/tmp:                  976c
```

which are always the fd's associated with a systemd process running as the same user:

```
$ id
uid=1001(jhnc) gid=1001(jhnc) groups=1001(jhnc)

$ ps -O user 941
    PID USER     S TTY          TIME COMMAND
    941 jhnc     S ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

A non-root Ubuntu 20.04 user also sees these errors; but the associated process is `sidekiq` and not the equivalent `systemd`.

The Ubuntu 18.04 and 22.04 and Archlinux appear ok: the non-root users do not get error messages.

On debian, these errors did not happen before the Ubuntu upgrade. I'm not sure about the 20.04 container.

I see nothing in /var/log on either host or container.

My searches have brought up very old discussions of apparmor, capabilities, and cgroups. I don't know much about any of these so unsure of relevance.

---

What was the change in Ubuntu 22.04 that is the underlying cause of these permission errors?